# using reference libraries in android

Tags: android, package

Have a great day...

I am still stuck with my bug...
I am using an android app. to login a website using the twitter account..
I am using the twitter4j api for this...
I have imported the classes from the jar files to my activity...
I also have my activity 'MainActivity'added in the manifest file..
but still the application is force closing ...!
Any one have an Idea..?

LogCat Error:
[Error](http://paste.org/pastebin/api/27529)

Comment: There is no idea until you won't post what exception is occurring.

Comment: Please include output from logcat with full Exception stack trace.

Comment: you can also post your code or error log here. Please do not refer other sites for this **`Stackoverflow`** has everything.

Answer (score 0):

checkNotBuilt of ConfigurationBuilder class is throwing exception, probably before calling setOAuthConsumerKey API in onCreate, it may be required to initialize some configuration.

I never used twitter4j and can just give this pointer to debug further.